# mysql query fetch all records from a coloumns whoes first 3 letters are alpha(charachert)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mytable
-------
addressColoumn
1 street
2 street
my address
your address

select address from mytable where addressColoumn= (first 3 character as alpha(character))
```

so it should return two records

```
my address
your address
```

what will be the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example I'm guessing you mean A-Z, in caps or lowercase, and/or space.

For SQL Server:

```
where addressColoumn like '[a-z ][a-z ][a-z ]%'
```

For MySQL:

```
where addressColoumn REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]'
```

For Oracle:

```
where regexp_like (addressColoumn, '^[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]')
```

Of course, you can also reverse the condition, and check for a numeric first character.  Should be easy to adopt the above snippets for that.

Comment: I ran this query select address from mytable where addressColoumn REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]'
but it returns empty result set. sorry i forget to mention. I am using mysql

Comment: sorry my mistake. it is working fine. i mistakenly placed the % sign in search. thanks